# Continuous toggle in PHP

Tags: php, forms, togglebutton

I want the text in div to switch from "PL" to "EN" and back. However, once the button is clicked and it's switched to EN, it doesn't want to go back to PL after I click it once again.

```
<body>
            <?php
                $lang=false;

                if (isset($_GET['toggle'])) {
                    if ($lang==false) $lang=true;
                    else $lang=false;
                    //unset($_GET['toggle']);
                }

                if ($lang==false) {
                    $text="PL";
                }
                if ($lang==true) {
                    $text="EN";
                }
            ?>

            <div>
                <?php echo $text; ?>
                <form method="get">
                    <input name="toggle" type="submit" value="Click!" />
                </form>
            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it's because the value isn't preserved anywhere. Either use a session or include a hidden input to always send the current state of $lang. You also always re-set `$lang` here `$lang=false;`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that explains everything :)